# Example of periodic semidifferentiable function without absolutely convergent Fourier series

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, fourier-analysis

Is there an example of a periodic continuous function that is semidifferentiable (i.e the left derivative and the right derivative exist at each point), but
with a non-absolutely convergent Fourier series ?

Comment: What is the answer if the function is differentiable (with very discontinuous derivative)?